# AWS API Gateway Routing multi parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

How to pass multi parameters in API routes from AWS console

```
/nodes/{id}&{limit}
```

> this routing got One or more path parts appear to be invalid. Parts
> are validated against this regular expression:
> ^({[\w.:-]++?}|[a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]+)$

Comment: Take a look on this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html

Comment: Feel free to answer your solution